# assume_role does not return and lambda times out (keywords: aws boto3 sts lambda python3.6)

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.6, boto3, aws-sts, assume-role

I am attempting to create a python3.6 AWS lambda function that assumes a role in another account to access an S3 bucket in that another account. I am testing this exact lambda function locally (with aws profile set) to test whether my cross account roles and policies are set up and locally it works flawlessly. However, when running the same code from within lambda it looks like assume_role does not return and the lambda times out. Would appreciate any hint how to approach debugging this or any ideas what could be an issue?

My code:

```
print ("==== before_assume_role")
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role( 
    RoleArn=FOREIGN_ROLE_TO_ASSUME, RoleSessionName='cross-account-session')
print ("==== after_assume_role")
```

"==== after_assume_role" does not get printed out, error handler (i.e. `except (Exception) as error`) does not get called and lambda times out.

Any ideas would be extremely appreciated!

Thank you,
Constantine

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having this problem right now.

Comment: No I did not resolve it despite browsing a ton of posts and attempting many tweaks. Instead, I created a designated REST API in another account with an API key and accessing that API from the first account.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue as well, the reason was I was deploying it in a private VPC. My fix was to specify the sts client explicitly.

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts',region_name="ap-southeast-1",endpoint_url="https://sts.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com")
```

Change the region name and endpoint url accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It turns out that an internet connection is required to run that function, and if you are using a custom vpc you don't get that by default.

### Diagnostic

This is most likely failing:

```py
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://www.google.com', timeout=5)
        # return {"message": f"internet connection is working: {r}"}
        print(f"internet connection is working: {r}")
    except BaseException as e:
        print(f"internet connection is not working: {e}")
```

### Solution (getting internet access):

You should first make sure that you select a public subnet when creating the VPC connector

Then, when the lambda service is deployed follow the next steps:

- Go to the network interfaces section, inside VPC module, and you will find one interface with a description starting AWS Lambda VPC ENI... that belongs to the public subnet you choose when creating the lambda service. That's the network interface of your lambda service. Note down the id of that network interface, eni-...
- Now go to elastic ip, in the VPC module aswell, and allocate a new elastic ip address.
  Then, select the new elastic ip and, under the actions button, select associate elastic ip. There, choose network interface and select the network interface id of the step 1.
- After that, check the lambda function again and you should have internet connectivity.